# PDF view and modify. on PowerApps

Tags: pdf, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to view and add some comments or signatures to PDF files using PowerApps, but it seems that there is a limitation to making this on PowerApps out of the box tools and components.

so, is there any other solution or third-party tool to integrate it with PowerApps to Achieve this?

thanks, and best regards.

Comment: Check Adobe or DocuSign connectors if it helps for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several third-party tools that can be used to add comments and signatures to PDF files within PowerApps. Some popular options include:

Adobe Acrobat DC: This is a paid tool that can be used to view and add comments and signatures to PDF files within PowerApps. You can use the Adobe Acrobat DC connector to connect to the Adobe Acrobat DC API and integrate it with your PowerApps app.

DocuSign: This is a popular electronic signature tool that can be used to add signatures to PDF files within PowerApps. You can use the DocuSign connector to connect to the DocuSign API and integrate it with your PowerApps app.

Microsoft Office 365: Office 365 includes a built-in PDF viewer that allows users to add comments and signatures to PDF files.

Foxit PhantomPDF: Foxit PhantomPDF is a paid tool that can be used to view and add comments and signatures to PDF files within PowerApps.

PDF.js: PDF.js is an open-source JavaScript library that can be used to view and add comments and signatures to PDF files within PowerApps.

It's important to note that the availability of these solutions may vary depending on the region or location. Some of the above solutions may require additional setup or configuration in order to work with PowerApps. I recommend checking the official documentation of each solution for more information on how to set them up and use them with PowerApps.